# Don't install a RPM if a dependancy installation fails on %pre* sections

Tags: rpm, specifications, failed-installation

I'm making several rpm with some dependancies between each other.

Problem is, when a dependancy installation fails in %pre or %pretrans section with exit code -1, the next rpm is still installed whereas it requires the dependancy that failed.

So my rpm is installed, but his dependancies are not ... it can't work.

Is it possible to force rpm installation to abort if at least one dependancy installation fails ?

I'm using yum for installing.

Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

There were several discussions on this issue. The bottom line is: YUM installs the package and all dependencies as a single RPM transaction, so it installs packages even if a dependency failed in %pre. The solution is, in your RPM %pre, check that the dependency was installed correctly, but note that you cannot use rpm command within your %pre.